# If the image of a map from a Lie group is open, then is its differential onto?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-functions

Let $G$ a simply connected Lie group, $E$ a finite-dimensional real vector space and $\pi:G\to E $  a smooth map such that its image $\pi(G)$ is open in $E$. Can I assure that the differential at the identity $\pi_{*,\epsilon}$ is onto? In the other way, if I know that the differential is onto, can I prove that $\pi(G)$ must be open?

Comment: I was dealing w this: Let $\rho$ an affine representation of a Lie group $G$, $\rho:G\to\it{aff}(\mathfrak{g})$, such that the isotropy group of $0$ is discrete and the orbit of $0$ is open. If $\pi:G\to\mathfrak{g}$ is the orbital map at $0$, that is, $\pi(g)=\rho(g)(0)$, I was trying to prove that its differential $\pi_{*,\epsilon}$ must be an isomorphism. I know that the kernel of the differential $\pi_{*,\epsilon}$ is the Lie algebra of the isotropy group; hence, the isotropy group being discrete implies $\pi_{*,\epsilon}$ is one-to-one. I'm stuck with the proof that this map must be onto.

Answer (score 2):

Neither implication is necessarily true.

Consider the special case $G = \mathbb{R}$ and $E = \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map $x \mapsto x^3$. Then the differential of $\pi_1$ at the identity is not onto, but the image of $\pi_1$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which is open.

Let $\pi_2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map $x \mapsto \sin(x)$. Then the differential of $\pi_2$ at the identity is onto, but the image of $\pi_1$ is $[-1,1]$, which is not open.